# student result with their position in class

Tags: php

I need help on this script, I printed out the student result and try to get their position in class.

```
<html>
<body>
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><p align="center"><strong>Student     Name</strong></p></td>
<td><p align="center"><strong>Computer</strong></p></td>
<td><p align="center"><strong>Position</strong></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>Agbo Cynthia </p></td>
<td><p>21.0</p></td>
<td><p> </p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>Nwoye Ugochukwu </p></td>
<td><p>76.0</p></td>
<td><p></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>Ogburie Kosisochukwu </p></td>
<td><p>28.0</p></td>
<td><p> </p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>Okechukwu Onyeka </p></td>
<td><p>38.0</p></td>
<td><p> </p></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Having try scripts to determine the student position base on their score that have in db, I could not eventually get the right script. 
I make use of this scripts bellow, but it repeating scores value.

$row['comp'] is the scores from each student from db

```
<?php
$grades = array(''.$row['comp'].'');
$occurrences = array_count_values($grades);
$grades = array_unique($grades);
foreach($grades as $grade) 
   {
echo str_repeat($grade .' - '.($i+1).'<br>',$occurrences[$grade]);
$i += $occurrences[$grade];
   }
?>
```

What I want is a script that will give the student in the class their position according to the computer score in db

Comment: Of course you should not have to write all numbers out(so use answers from below) but in case you have something similar you could use `in_array` as `in_array($pross['posi'], [1, 11, 21, 31, ...]) === true` instead of a lot of ors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an OR (||) you cannot only check the second value, you need to recheck each element.
(Example)

```
if($a == $b || $a == $c)
```

Can you force like this?

```
if (substr($pross['posi'], -1) == 1 && $pross['posi'] != 11){
     echo $pross['posi'].'st';
} elseif(substr($pross['posi'], -1) == 2 && $pross['posi'] != 12){
     echo $pross['posi'].'nd';
} else {
     echo $pross['posi'].'th';
}
```

I'm forcing the value to string, then i check the last value of each string.

Comment: You still need to exclude 11 and 12 from the ifs. So the first if line becomes `if (substr($pross['posi'], -1) == 1 && $pross['posi'] !== 11)`. Or better yet, do another substring check on 11(because of 111 etc.). I have not checked if there any locale option or library for this, if there is; use that =)

Comment: added it =) (even for 12)

Comment: it works... thanks, i just edit my question... view it kindly

Answer (score 0):

1. `if($pross['posi'] % 10 === 1)` is way more readable;
2. The code evaluated is actually:

   if ( ( $pross['posi'] == 1 ) || ( 21 ) ) ...

Apparently `21` evaluates to `true`. To achieve what you wanted you should repeat

```
$var === 1 || $var === 11 || ...
```

or use a modulo calc I introduced above.

Comment: it works... thanks, i just edit my question... view it kindly